# how to keep a service alive without an ongoing notification

Tags: android, service

I know i can use an ongoing notification to keep my service alive but i have a service that is holding a broadcast receiver. I do not want to use a notification to simply hold my broadcast receiver. I know also i can register my receiver inside my app's manifest but i want the user to be able to control if the receiver is active or not.

Here is the service that keeps restarting.

```
public class DockServiceListener extends Service{

IntentFilter filter;
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Receiver started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHOR

    filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT);
    mReceiver = new DockReceiver();

}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int id) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, START_STICKY, id);

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    return id;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Very simple. I also know it may be android cleaning up but how come Facebook messenger and other service's arent being closed? Unless i just dont know it cause it doesnt have the toast message? Or is there a way to only run onCreate once?

Well anyhow, thanks everyone for looking! Hopefully someone can better educate me! :)

EDIT: New method wondering if this is right?

```
startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            ComponentName dockReceiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), DockReceiver.class);
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(dockReceiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 0);
            finish();



        }
    });

    stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            ComponentName dockReceiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), DockReceiver.class);
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(dockReceiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know also i can register my receiver inside my app's manifest but i want the user to be able to control if the receiver is active or not.

Then use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to enable or disable your `BroadcastReceiver` that is registered in the manifest. You not need to waste the user's RAM with a service just to control whether "the receiver is active or not".

Comment: I edited my question, is the new edit the right way? It seems to be working. I activated it inside my Manifest and it seems to be doing the job with the buttons. Just wondering if my syntax and location is correct.  I did change the "0" to a "-1" and it seems smoother.

Comment: @Seth: You can get rid of `getApplicationContext()` wherever you see it. And I have no idea if `finish()` is necessary or not, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: i call `finish()` on the button click so the user doesnt have to manually press the back button or home button to leave my activity. Just trying to remove an unneeded step for the user. And it errors out when i remove `getApplicationContext()` since there is no Context argument. This is what eclipse is saying "ComponentName(Context, <class name>)" it works when i include `getApplicationContext()` is there something else i should use instead?

Comment: @Seth: Use `WhateverYourActivityNameIs.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`. Only call `getApplicationContext()` when you know *precisely and specifically why* you are calling `getApplicationContext()`. Whatever you are calling `getApplicationContext()` on *is a `Context`* already, so you do not need to call `getApplicationContext()` just to get a `Context`.

Comment: Oh, okay.. I must have misunderstood the use of `getApplicationContext()` cause both methods work. And for the heck of it i did a toast message of `getApplicationContext()` and it returns the same thing as `ActivityName.this` so i just always used `getApplicationContext()` 

Thanks for all your help btw!